# How to convert a Png or Jpeg to Tiff?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, stream

I'm trying to convert a Png or Jpg file to Tiff format. Here is my code:

```
    ' If png or jpeg, then convert to Tiff
    If aFName.ToUpper.EndsWith(".PNG") OrElse aFName.ToUpper.EndsWith(".JPG") OrElse aFName.ToUpper.EndsWith(".JPEG") Then
        Try
            lTiffMS = New MemoryStream
            System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(lMS).Save(lTiffMS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
            lTiffMS.CopyTo(lMS)
            aFName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(aFName) + ".tiff"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Common.LogMessage("SAPInterface.GetBase64-Tiff", ex.ToString)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End If
  
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(lMS.ToArray())
```

The original image is in `lMS`. I save it into `lTiff` and then copy it back to `lMS` (as I need to have it there)

The issue is that the `lMS` stream still contains the original file instead of the expected Tiff image. I'm not very good with memory streams. Is this the correct way to convert?

Comment: The line that calls `Inage.FromStream` is bad. ALWAYS dispose the objects you create if they support it. You are creating an `Image` object and not retaining a reference, so that object is not disposed and can never be, so it will sit around using resources pointlessly unti the GC gets around to cleaning it up. You should be creating the `Image` with a `Using` statement and calling `Save` within the block. The `Image` object will then be disposed implicitly at the `End Using` line. ALWAYS create short-lived, disposable objects with a `Using` statement so they are disposed that way.

Comment: A `MemoryStream` is disposable too, so it should also be being created with a `Using` block.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney . Will update the code to use Using.

Comment: You cannot overwrite the Stream used to load the image. You can dispose of the original Stream (as already suggested), delete the original file, then save a new file with the same name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by simply setting `lMS = lTiffMS`.

```
' If png or jpeg, then convert to Tiff
If aFName.ToUpper.EndsWith(".PNG") OrElse aFName.ToUpper.EndsWith(".JPG") OrElse aFName.ToUpper.EndsWith(".JPEG") Then
    Try
        Using lTiffMS As New MemoryStream
            Using lImg As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(lMS)
                lImg.Save(lTiffMS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff)
            End Using
            lMS = lTiffMS
        End Using
        aFName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(aFName) + ".tiff"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Common.LogMessage("SAPInterface.GetBase64-Tiff", ex.ToString)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End If

Return Convert.ToBase64String(lMS.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

A stream has a pointer that indicates where the next read or write will be performed. As you read or write, that pointer is advanced. When you call `Image.FromStream`, you read the entire stream and so advance the pointer to the end of the stream. If you then expect to overwrite the contents of the stream, you need to reset that pointer to the beginning of the stream. You can do that by setting the `Position` property or calling the `Seek` method. This is assuming that the `CanSeek` property is `True`, which it will be for a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: So I need to set `lMS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` before the CopyTo call?